# C: "Conflicting types for ..." error

Tags: c

Lets assume that I have 2 header files:

`add.h`

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
int summation = 0;

void add();
```

`sub.h`

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
int subtraction = 0;

void subtract();
```

and their `.c` files:

`add.c`

```
#include "add.h"

void add()
{
    summation = num1 + num2;
}
```

`sub.c`

```
#include "sub.h"

void sub()
{
    subtraction = num1 - num2;
}
```

and the main `.c` file:

`calc.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "add.h"
#include "sub.h"

int main()
{
    /*rest of code*/
    return 0;
}
```

lets assume that I need to use the 2 header files variable(s) and function(s) in `calc.c` without changing anything in them or their `.c` files.

Comment: and I guess the conflict is for `num1` and `num2`...:)

Comment: I'd strongly advice you against declaring global storage on header files. Header files are not intended for storage, but for types and function definitions.

Comment: These .h are broken : they *define* the ints instead of just declaring them. They are strictly unusable wihout modification.

Comment: You also seem to mix up `summation` and `addition`. Also, `subtraction = num1 + num2` does not look like a subtraction.

Comment: @Jens sorry for that, edited now

Answer (score 0):

Because both `add.h` and `sub.h` contain this:

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
```

The declarations interfere with each other.  This is a good example of why global variables are bad.

Your functions should instead be designed to take the parameters they require and return a result:

```
int add(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}

int sub(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 - num2;
}
```

Comment: This means that I have to re-design ```add``` and ```sub``` .. and I don't want that.

Comment: @BaronLeonardo Why not?  It's a bad design for exactly the reason I mentioned.

Comment: This is an example for a situation I have ..
In this situation I must use global variables and include the 2 header files that have the same variable name.

Comment: @BaronLeonardo Is there any reason to declare them in the header. You shouldn't do that. Declare them in the file and keep them file-local.

Comment: @BaronLeonardo In that case, can you post a more concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef _NUMDEF_
#define _NUMDEF_
int num1, num2;
#else
extern int num1, num2;
#endif
```

Edit both `add.h` and `sub.h` if you are uncompromising about your design, though many programmers might frown upon on such an approach. Further assign values to `num1` and `num2` in `add.c` and `sub.c`.

It is better to create new header file with above code and include it in both `add.h` and `sub.h`.

Comment: This is useless. If both add.c and sub.c include the header, you still have multiply defined symbols. It is simply WRONG to define objects in a header. Any book on C will teach the correct technique.

Comment: @user3400391 you'me missing `extern`.

Comment: @Jens : I am able to compile it.